# Simple Prowl notifications for After Effects render completion

Tags: after-effects, script

I want to be able to receive push notifications to my iPhone when After Effects completes a render.

I used to use [Prowl](http://www.prowlapp.com/) v1.5.2 & [Growl](http://growl.info/) v2.1.3 combined with [this script](http://iaian7.com/aftereffects/iPhoneRenderNotifications) ([.jsx file](http://iaian7.com/files/aftereffects/rendernotifications/Render_Notify_14.jsx))to do this, but I can't get the script to work now.

I can get [growlnotify](http://growl.info/downloads#growlnotify) to send a notification from the terminal to Growl, and successfully pass it to Prowl on my iPhone, but when I tried this script, it fails at line 24.  I've added the API key, and chosen growl as the notification type.  Growlnotify is in usr/local/bin and my appname is set to Adobe After Effects CC 2015.

I don't need background rendering, just a simple notify when renders complete.

I'm using OSX 10.11.1 and iOS 9.2, and After Effects CC 2015 v13.6.0.165

Here's a script example, it's only two lines:

```
app.project.renderQueue.render();
function(){system.callSystem(“Open growlnotify")};
```

First line renders the queue (without any safety checking)
Second line should open growlnotify to send a default message

First line works, second line doesn't - it returns "Syntax Error".  I've also tried:

```
app.project.renderQueue.render();
function(){system.callSystem(“growlnotify")};
```

Comment: Maybe, paste your script (with the API key obscured).

Comment: Good idea - done.

Comment: Can you use full path to invoke growl?

Comment: And I meant the script whose line 24 fails.

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't work.  From the terminal, I can invoke growlnotify from any directory.

Comment: I linked to the big script (see http://iaian7.com/files/aftereffects/rendernotifications/Render_Notify_14.jsx) , because it's huge and more complex than I need (and it too doesn't work any more)

Comment: Your two line scripts have a closing quote missing in 2nd line.

Comment: Oops - fixed the missing quote.  It was there before.. The script doesn't run - I get "Unable to execute script at line 2. Syntax error" for both versions (with and without "open")

Comment: Just another guess, but in the JSX script, there is no function() invoked before the system calls. And the `MAIN` function isn't explicitly stated either, just curly brackets, so try leaving out function() and/or the curly brackets.

Comment: with no function, still get Syntax Error.  With no curly brackets and no function, syntax error.  With function but no curly brackets, I get "expected {".  I wonder if the scripting language changed since Creative Suite became Creative Cloud?

Comment: Try single quotes and no function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script extract you include:

```
app.project.renderQueue.render();
function(){system.callSystem(“Open growlnotify")};
```

has a dodgy opening quote.  “ is not the same as " - this is why you are getting the syntax error.

```
app.project.renderQueue.render();
(function(){system.callSystem("Open growlnotify")})();
```

works (the (..)() calls the anonymous function). You need to add the parentheses so that the anonymous function gets called, or simply do `system.callSystem("Open growlnotify");` without the anonymous function.

You also need to activate "allow scripts to write files and access network" in Preferences/General, otherwise `callSystem` is blocked.

In the full script you post, when you replaced `type = "web"` on line 24 to use growl, the same error probably slipped in.  Check your keyboard autocorrect settings to ensure that you've not got curly quotes.

Comment: Thanks - that is very helpful - it stops the syntax error!  But I still don't get growlnotify running!

Comment: But it does fix the Render_Notify_14.jsx file I linked to, so that works for me!  Thanks again.